# iPhone - Get Position of UIView within entire UIWindow

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiwindow

The position of a `UIView` can obviously be determined by `view.center` or `view.frame` etc. but this only returns the position of the `UIView` in relation to it's immediate superview.

I need to determine the position of the `UIView` in the entire 320x480 co-ordinate system. For example, if the `UIView` is in a `UITableViewCell` it's position within the window could change dramatically irregardless of the superview.

Any ideas if and how this is possible?

Answer (score 366, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
[aView convertPoint:localPosition toView:nil];
```

... converts a point in local coordinate space to window coordinates. You can use this method to calculate a view's origin in window space like this:

```
[aView.superview convertPoint:aView.frame.origin toView:nil];
```

**2014 Edit:** Looking at the popularity of Matt__C's comment it seems reasonable to point out that the coordinates...

1. don't change when rotating the device.
2. always have their origin in the top left corner of the unrotated screen.
3. are **window coordinates**: The coordinate system ist defined by the bounds of the window. The screen's and device coordinate systems are different and should not be mixed up with window coordinates.

Comment: Be aware that specifying nil in the toView parameter gives you device co-ordinates, which won't be what you want if you are not in portrait orientation. See [convertpointtoview-in-landscape-mode-giving-wrong-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452716/convertpointtoview-in-landscape-mode-giving-wrong-values)

Comment: @Matt__C: Specifying nil calculates **window coordinates**, not device coordinates. If you want device coordinates you have to further convert using UIWindow's conversion methods.

Comment: This method kept returning `aView.frame.origin` for me. It took me a whlie to realize my view's superview did not have a superview itself.

Comment: If your superView did not have a superView your view should not be seen at all

Comment: @JimThio To be super-precise: If the view's superview was a window it **would** be visible. On iOS `UIWindow` derives fron `UIView`.

Comment: Adapting @Matt__C linked solution to your case, it would become: `[view.superview convertPoint:view.frame.origin toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view]`

Answer (score 79):

**Swift 5+**:

```
let globalPoint = aView.superview?.convert(aView.frame.origin, to: nil)
```

Comment: its OMG.. what a great func!

Answer (score 47):

Using extension:

```
extension UIView{
    var globalPoint :CGPoint? {
        return self.superview?.convert(self.frame.origin, to: nil)
    }
    
    var globalFrame :CGRect? {
        return self.superview?.convert(self.frame, to: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

In Swift:

```
let globalPoint = aView.superview?.convertPoint(aView.frame.origin, toView: nil)
```

Answer (score 28):

Here is a combination of the answer by @Mohsenasm and a comment from @Ghigo adopted to Swift

```
extension UIView {
    var globalFrame: CGRect? {
        let rootView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view
        return self.superview?.convert(self.frame, to: rootView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this code worked best:

```
private func getCoordinate(_ view: UIView) -> CGPoint {
    var x = view.frame.origin.x
    var y = view.frame.origin.y
    var oldView = view

    while let superView = oldView.superview {
        x += superView.frame.origin.x
        y += superView.frame.origin.y
        if superView.next is UIViewController {
            break //superView is the rootView of a UIViewController
        }
        oldView = superView
    }

    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

Comment: i don't think using while loop is a good idea in a UI.

Answer (score 4):

Works well for me :)

```swift
extension UIView {
    var globalFrame: CGRect {
        return convert(bounds, to: window)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
view.layoutIfNeeded() // this might be necessary depending on when you need to get the frame

guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }

let frame = yourView.convert(yourView.bounds, to: keyWindow)

print("frame: ", frame)
```