# get UIButton inside an UIScrollView absolute screen location

Tags: xcode, screen-positioning

It may be a dumb question, but I can't find an answer to this ...

I have an UIScrollView and inside a number of UIButtons. 
When I press a button, I want to know the screen location of the button. If I use button.frame it gives me the position inside UIScrollView, which is normal.

How can I find x and y relative to screen of the button pressed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your objection was right- instead, use

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

from UIView, like

```
[button.superview convertPoint:button.frame.origin toView:nil];
```

Not tested, but I believe that should work. Also see [iPhone - Get Position of UIView within entire UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow)

Comment: If I scroll horizontally the UIScrollView, I may have button.frame.origin.x = 1017 or something, so your example will not be correct.

Answer (score 7):

For swift:

```
let pointXY:CGPoint = (button.superview?.convert(button.frame.origin, to: nil))!
print("button pointXY: \(pointXY.debugDescription)")
```

Comment: Saved my lot of time, I'm finding this for the last 3 hours, Thank u so much