# Sending actions from a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with 10 buttons, each button has its own method. My goal is to activate each button when the user scrolls and the `UIButton` is "entering" a specific area. What's a good way to accomplish that? (I don't want the `UIButton` to be pushed. Just hovering on it should activate it)

Example:

---

button 1

button 2

**ooooooo**

button 3         **<--activated**

**ooooooo**

button 4

---

Right now button 3 is activated. If the user will scroll down a bit button 2 will be activated.

Comment: This post shows how to get the absolute position for a button inside the scroll view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626411/get-uibutton-inside-an-uiscrollview-absolute-screen-location

Comment: if the buttons have no purpose other than to trigger an action, would it be easier to define a region on the view, and then if the underlying scrollview moves, check which region of the scrollview is corresponging with the view, and call a method based on the x,y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by activated you mean **uicontrolstate** of the button being **enabled** or not. The most straight forward way I can think to do this is by doing something similar to BloonsTowerDefence and look at the **uiscrollviews**  **contentoffset** and at various ranges you will examine the **contentoffset** and disable all the rest of the buttons and enable the button you would like to be enabled at that range.