# I get the same position of a UIButton inside a UIScrollView if I scroll down or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I want to get the position of a **UIButton** inside a **UIScrollView** the problem is that i get the same position for when the **UIButton** is in it’s original position or if I scroll down…

I’m using **NSLog** to print the position and I get the same output

- Without scroll down i get...

  ```
  2014-11-05 19:28:02.564 ... {{260, 163}, {370, 225}}
  ```
- Even if I scroll down I get the same output...

  ```
  2014-11-05 19:28:06.052 ... {{260, 163}, {370, 225}}
  ```

This is the code i'm using to obtain the position of the **UIButton** inside the **UIScrollView**...

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectMake(myButton.frame.origin.x, myButton.frame.origin.y, myScrollDown.frame.size.width, myScrollDown.frame.size.height)));
```

**There is a way to get the actual position of the UIButton even after I scrolled down?**

**There is another way to get the position of the UIButton inside the ScrollView?**

I’ve already visited the following links and I have not resolved it yet.

[get UIButton inside an UIScrollView absolute screen location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626411/get-uibutton-inside-an-uiscrollview-absolute-screen-location)

[iPhone - Get Position of UIView within entire UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow)

[Cocoa: What's the difference between the frame and the bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect([self.view convertRect:myButton.frame fromView:myButton.superview]));
```

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I need it, with this i figure it out and now i can get the position, no matter if i scroll down or not, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the position within the scrollview.  Probably what you want is the position within the scrollview's superview (perhaps self.view, perhaps something else).

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll view is going to have a `contentOffset` value.  The frame of the subviews inside of the scroll view don't change when it scrolls.  Instead, this `contentOffset` value is changed.  I'm sure there are better ways to do this but on a basic level, you could just do something like so to get the frame in the scroll view's superview:

```
CGRect frame = myButton.frame;
frame.origin.x -= scrollView.contentOffset.x;
frame.origin.y -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame);
```

Comment: I used the code you posted and I tried to print the __contentOffset__ before and after scroll down and i got the same in both cases... I used __NSLog(@"contentOffset: (%f, %f)", MyScrollView.contentOffset.x, MyScrollView.contentOffset.y);__ in both cases and in both i got __contentOffset: (0.000000, 0.000000)__ What am I doing wrong?