# How do I reliably detect uiview frame's origin Y relative to the screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - Get Position of UIView within entire UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow)

Is there a built in method to do this? Or do I have to jump through all the superviews, sum all the Y origins until I reach mainWindow?

Answer (score 1):

This is à duplicate of [iPhone - Get Position of UIView within entire UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow)

Just use:

`[aView convertPoint:localPosition toView:nil];`

Comment: Instead of posting the duplicate answer, please vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: This is not the same question. I am interested in position relative to the physical screen. Not a window.

Comment: The window is the same as the screen. Try it.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right, sorry. Flagged as duplicate now.