# How to get absolute rect on screen of UIImageView

Tags: ios, cgrect

I need to resize an UImageView dynamically

for that I need to find the UImageview's absolute rect on screen, x,y is what i need actually.

because my ImageView is inside another view, if i query the ImageView frame, i get x,y of it to be 0,0

how do I find the absolute rect on screen ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow

Comment: [aView.superview convertPoint:aView.frame.origin toView:nil]; this fixed my probelm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
CGRect targetFrame = [self.view convertRect:imageView.frame fromView:imageView];
```

Comment: this returns 0,0 as the origin

Comment: in order to use the above method correctly please add the view hierarchy to your question so we can add the appropriate parameters