# UIView absolute screen point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgrect

Is there an easy way of getting the absolute point of UIView? By absolute I mean the location of the UIView relative to 1024x768 on an iPad?

I need an easy way because I have a UIButton inside a UITableViewCell inside a UITableView inside a view presented by a viewcontroller that is a child of another view controller repeating to the fifth or sixth view controller.
And due to this complex design I need the absolute rect of the UIButton so I can display an UIActionSheet on the "main" viewcontroller.

Comment: what do you mean by absolute? your example was unclear.

Comment: The origin on the screen. Earl Grey got it right :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I ended up using UITapGestureRecognizer instead and calculating the position like this:

```
    CGPoint gestureViewLocation = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    CGPoint absoluteLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.parentViewController.view];
    CGRect fromRect = CGRectMake(absoluteLocation.x-gestureViewLocation.x, //subtract to we get point relative to gesture view
                                 absoluteLocation.y-gestureViewLocation.y, //subtract to we get point relative to gesture view
                                 gesture.view.frame.size.width,
                                 gesture.view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 9):

So, we have a let's call it small view that has a certain point inside it. That point has **local coordinates** relative to its parent view that is small view.
Now, we want to know, **what would be the coordinates of that point** if it would stay in the same spot on the screen, but it would be part of the root view. (this effectively gives us the coordinates relative to the whole screen.)

You will calculate the global coordinates of that point

```
CGPoint globalCoordinates = [self.smallView convertPoint:localCoordinatesOfThePoint 
                                                  toView:self.view];
```

`localCoordinatesOfThePoint` is also a CGPoint structure.

**Another scenario**

is when you have the whole screen covered with root view, this has a large view, (still smaller than the root view though), and this large view has a small view as a subview inside it.

You will calculate the position of the small view's tip

```
CGPoint originOnScreen = [self.smallView convertPoint:self.smallview.origin 
                                               toView:self.view];
```

`self.smallview.origin` is a CGPoint relative to Large view. Thus, we calculate, what would be its coordinates if this point (it's the top-left tip of small view really) would be inside the root view.

**CATCH**

If the root view is not full screen, than instead of root view ,we need to get a reference to the main window as this will be our view against which we calculate coordinates now.

we have to

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

in our class where we calculate and then pass the window property as the reference view. It is guaranteed that window covers the screen and UIWindow is a subclass of UIView. So it just works.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

CGPoint originOnScreen = [self.smallView convertPoint:self.smallview.origin 
                                               toView:appDelegate.window];
```

Comment: I just cant seem to make it work. I've tried various scenarios of the above with no luck. I definitely missing something and I cant post my entire code as example, but I found a solution. See my answer

Comment: Well, sort of. The "appDelegate.window" seem to do the trick, but somehow I'm ending on origin.x being out of the screen. I just needs some adjustments. The easiest and most precise for me ended up as my answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you running your ipad build on Portrait or Landscape? I believe the offset is the delta between the widht and the hight of the screen. Besically they are swapped. Is that so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the coordinates of a `CGPoint`/ `CGRect` in a certain `UIView` you can use the `UIView` methods

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

or for `CGRect`

```
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view
```

in the first argument put the `CGPoint`/`CGRect` you want to convert and in the second put the `UIView` you want to convert to

Comment: My problem is that the button doesnt know the top level view (which also would be a bad design)

Comment: are you converting the CGRect from a subclass of UIButton or something?

Comment: I'm basically just trying to display an actionsheet from the UIButton

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point
                 toView:(UIView *)view
```

This will converts a point from the receiver’s coordinate system (your button) to that of the specified view (top level view).

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:)

Comment: My problem is that the button doesnt know the top level view (which also would be a bad design)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - see my comment on Earl Greys posts

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 convert that seems to work for a more than two levels of subviews:

```
// given that myView is in hierarchy of rootView, either
// have rootView convert its origin from myView, or
// have myView convert rootView's origin to rootView

rootView.convert(rootView.origin, from: myView)
var absView = myView.convert(rootView.origin, to: rootView)
```

I found the convert routine somewhat confusing. So, I brute force tested all the possible combinations with 5 levels of views. With the results [posted on github](https://github.com/musesum/TestConvertOrigin)

[Edit] When rootView is a UITableView, adjust for contentOffset:

```
 if let tableView = rootView as? UITableView {
        absView.y -= tableView.contentOffset.y
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert from a view's local frame or path to SCREEN coordinates, use the built-in converters:

`UIAccessibilityConvertPathToScreenCoordinates`

or

`UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates`

This does return a path or rect, but you can extract points from those.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works to get frame relative to superview.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the absolute frame of any view using the following method:

```
func getAbsoluteFrame(of view: UIView, rootViewController: UIViewController) -> CGRect {
    guard let parentView = view.superview else {
        print("Super view of this view is nil")
        return view.frame
    }
    
    return rootViewController.view.convert(view.frame, from: parentView)
}
```

You can get the rootViewController like this:

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController
```